# Unless Otherwise Noted

Tags: idioms, supplementation

I have a question about the phrase "*unless otherwise noted*":

> The game starts at 7:00pm ***unless otherwise noted***.

Is the part "*unless otherwise noted*" missing an "*it is*" between "*unless*" and "otherwise noted":

> The game starts at 7:00pm *unless* ***it is*** *otherwise noted*.

Or, is "*unless otherwise noted*" a set phrase and I should stop losing sleep over it?

Comment: It's a set phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a set phrase. The "it is" is understood/implied. However, there is nothing wrong with adding "it is" in the middle like you have.